# How to remove homepage navigation link on every page?

Tags: wordpress

I am working on one wordpress site. i have total three page in my site for ex: home, one and two. my problem is whenever i move from home page to another page like home to one page then home->one this type of navigation link shown on every page like home->name of page. how to remove this link.

Answer (score 1):

Which WordPress version you are using??

May be your theme support breadcrumb functionality.
You can check it from admin side.

Answer (score 1):

Try to find breadcrumb's code in your header.php(or index.php, etc) and delete or place it between 
`<!--breadcrumb's code-->`

If your theme has custom options menu and you can turn off breadcrumbs. Check it.

Answer (score 0):

Also double check if pages one and two are child pages of home.

[image: WP-Page Attributes]